# How to search the content of visited pages in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I tried searching in the Chrome's History (`chrome://history/`) for a word but it didn't find anything.

Is there an addon to search the content of visited pages?

Comment: [Yes.](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/history%20search)

Comment: @Synetech how about this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deeper-history-your-histo/aohgidnfhlaciophgjldellglmocdkfn

Comment: `I tried searching in the Chrome's History (chrome://history/) for a word but it didn't find anything.` What word? Was it a word that was in a page that you have visited in the past four months?

Comment: @avirk, I’ve never tried it, but it *sounds* promising (though it has no reviews).

Comment: You can visit https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity, and just do a full text search

Answer (score 0):

No you can't search the page with its content in the history but a very useful extension called [Sexy undo closed tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sexy-undo-close-tab/bcennaiejdjpomgmmohhpgnjlmpcjmbg?hl=en) can help you, it will keep the record more than history of chrome and easy to find the closed page with the search option with their title

Edit: You can try [deeper search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deeper-history-your-histo/aohgidnfhlaciophgjldellglmocdkfn) addon which can do the job for you. Install it and then in omnibox type **dh** and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and search the content and match the history of your browsing data.

Comment: `No you can't search the page with its content in the history` Actually you can; Chrome keeps a list of keywords from the contents of visited pages, that is why the history files are so large. People complained that the [history was getting too big](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16705), so they changed it so that Chrome only keeps the full history index for the past four months and deletes them for months before that. (It still keeps a record of URLs and dates for visits before that.)

Comment: @Synetech I put the word in the search tab "as we all know" which was appeared on one of my question on SU but search result return to null?

Comment: [It worked for me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OFQl2.png) Chrome only keeps the contents of pages for four months now; have you visited that page in the past four months?

Comment: Don't know why it is not working at my side then. May be any issue with my chrome. :(

Comment: What version are you using? Do you have any history-related extensions active? Try creating a temporary, dummy profile, visit a couple of pages with a lot of text (e.g., Wikipedia), then close Chrome (to make sure that it writes everything to the databases), and start it again with that profile and do a search.